# Open GTS build failed

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, tomcat6

Every thing is okay (Opengts dir & tomcat dir have permission 777) but i am getting this error again & again,  why--

executing `# sudo ant all` then i get this error

```
BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/OpenGTS_2.4.5/build.xml:111: CATALINA_HOME environment variable has not been defined.
    (make sure CATALINA_HOME is defined and exported to the list of environment variables)
```

I got the this msg when starting the tomcat

```
sudo ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.36
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.36
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

Any one have the solution please tell me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

Try to configure OpenGTS in your home directory (rather than /usr/local/).

And use ant all command (not sudo ant all).

Good Lock.. :)

Answer (score 1):

First run this command:

```
echo $CATALINA_HOME
```

It should give you the path to your tomcat directory, which I'm assuming is `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.36`, but if you see a different path, or if the response is blank, try running this command:

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.36
```

If you read the [OpenGTS Configuration Manual](http://opengts.sourceforge.net/OpenGTS_Config.pdf), it talks about the CATALINA_HOME environment variable for Linux in section 2.4a. There are other environment variables too that you must set to install OpenGTS successfully (All mentioned in the manual).

Comment: I have set the following variables but still getting the same previous build failed error---  [ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-0F-C9-9B OpenGTS_2.4.5]$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-0F-C9-9B OpenGTS_2.4.5]$ export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-0F-C9-9B OpenGTS_2.4.5]$ export GTS_HOME=/usr/local/OpenGTS_2.4.5/

Comment: any one have the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, ensure the OpenGTS2.6.x has all files and directories to user:group same as logged in user. then run / ant all command

Please note that "sudo ant all" doesn't work.

Use this command to change ownership of OpenGTS files/dir

> /usr/local/OpenGTS2.6.2> cd ..
>
> sudo chown -R ranjan:ranjan OpenGTS2.6.2

change ranjan to your username: group name

> /usr/local/OpenGTS2.6.2> ant all

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install tomcat7 rather than tomcat6 via command line

```
apt-get update
apt-get install tomcat7
```

Configure CATALINA_HOME by

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7
```